# Adding kernel module to Debian

Tags: linux, arm, debian, kernel-module

I have imx6-quad and Debian Jessie installed on it. Here is the full info about (`uname -a`):

```
Linux linaro-alip 4.1.15-g5599520 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jan 8 13:03:20 IST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I'm trying to run tunslip application for CC1350 Launchpad, but there is no kernel module "tun" in my OS. When I run command `modprobe tun`, I given an error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module tun not found.
```

At this point, I don't know how to install tun module to my Debian. I even don't know where to start. Is it possible to add tun module to running operation system or should I compile whole kernel from scratch? If I can add kernel module, how could I add to running OS?

Any help is too precious for me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww, there are plenty of questions related to `kernel` and `kernel modules` in stackoverflow. Why do you think that my question is inappropriate for stackoverflow?

Comment: You are not being singled out. There are lots of off-topic questions on Stack overflow. Stack Overflow has become a dumping ground. The custom close message is provided to get you pointed in the right direction because the site does such a poor job of educating folks. Once you know about Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, you will likely use it (and the answers are often better for questions like these).

Comment: `there are plenty of questions related to kernel and kernel modules in stackoverflow. Why do you think that my question is inappropriate for stackoverflow?` - Questions about **writting** own kernel modules are **on-topic**, because they are **programming** question. But the questions about *using* system kernel modules, like given question, are *off-topic* because they are *not related to programming*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to sum up the discussion in the comments in case someone else will come here with the same problem:

Unfortunately, the precompiled kernel image provided by Variscite [here](http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=VAR-SOM-MX6_Debian_Recovery_SD_card) doesn't come with `tun` support at all. Neither in modules nor compiled into the kernel.

If you want `tun` support, you will have to compile the kernel in your own. Sources can be found [here on github](https://github.com/varigit/linux-2.6-imx).

---

**Previous Answer:**

Since I'm not allowed to comment yet, please take this less as an answer but more as a suggestion where to look for a solution.

What does the following command give you?

```
cat /boot/config-4.1.15-g5599520 | grep CONFIG_TUN
```

It should say `CONFIG_TUN=m`. If it doesn't, it may be that your kernel already supports tun devices.

Have you tried searching for `tun`modules in `/lib/modules`? If not, run

```
find /lib/modules/ -name '*tun.ko*'
```

and let us know what it gives you.

Comment: The `/boot` directory is empty, and there is not `tun` modules in `/lib/modules` folder. I'm running OS from sdcard btw.

Comment: Did you install the kernel via `apt-get` or did you build your own?

Comment: It's custom kernel which you can find in https://github.com/varigit/linux-2.6-imx. I used pre-compiled disk image, not builded own my own.

Comment: Where is the pre-compiled image located? I can only find source code in this git repo.

Comment: I'm sorry, here is the guide while I creating the sdcard. http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=VAR-SOM-MX6_Debian_Recovery_SD_card

Comment: Looks like they don't provide config information about whether or not they ship tun kernel modules. Have you tried to look whether the module is built in? `cat /lib/modules/4.1.15-g5599520/modules.builtin | grep tun`

Comment: There are some modules but none of them is tun that I want. `ip_tunnel.ko` `tunnel4.ko` and directory of `tuners`.

Comment: Looks like they didn't build with `tun` support at all then.

Comment: So as far as I understand, to be able to use `tun` kernel module or something else that is not in `/lib/modules`, I have to declare that while compiling kernel?

Comment: Yes, you will have to recompile. But since they don't provide a config to start with as far as I can see, you'll have to more or less build your own from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

as you are building your kernel. there are a couple of methods one is to compile the module separately and to install it on the existing image. The other is to create the tun module along with the kernel and the sdcard image creation will take care of your module.

TO build tun module. use `menuconfig` from the kernel folder. search for something matching to `CONFIG_TUN` if its is a module change its value to `m`. Rebuild and create the sdcard again. This is the easy way.

You can also craete the module separately and then bring the module to your filesystem but that can be more error prone.